# Support and range projections in von Neumann algebra

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

There is a quotation below:

Let $M$ be a von Neumann algebra, take a noncentral projection $p\in M$ and find some $m\in M$ such that $pm(1-p)\neq0$. The partial isometry in the polar decomposition of this operator will have orthogonal support and range projections.

**I could not understand why "the partial isometry in the polar decomposition of this operator will have orthogonal support and range projections." Could someone explain to me ? Thanks.**

Comment: Compare the support and range projections with $p$ and $1-p$. As $p$ and $1-p$ are orthogonal, so too are the support and range projections of $pm(1-p)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the polar decomposition $x=v|x|$, the partial isometry $v$ maps the range of $x^*$ into the range of $x$. The former is below $(1-p)$, while the latter is below $p$.

Comment: As we know, the polar decomposition is $ pm(1−p)=u|pm(1−p)|$, the $u^{*}u$ is the range projection of $|pm(1−p)|$, but what about the support projection $uu^{*}$? I am sorry, I am not sure about the definition of support projection here.

Comment: The range projection $p$ of $x$ is the smallest projection with $px=x$. The support of $x$ is the smallest projection with $xp=x$.

Comment: So, $uu^{*}$ is the support projection of $|pm(1-p)|$ , the $u^{*}u$ and $uu^{*}$ are orthogonal, right?

Comment: No. An absolute value is selfadjoint, so its range and support projections are equal. Like I said in the answer, if $x=v|x|$ is the polar decomposition, then $v^*v$ is the range projection of $x^*$ and $vv^*$ is the range projection of $x$.

Comment: Oh, my god. I have read a book " An introduction to the classification of amenable C*-algebras" by H Lin. In this book, the author says if $x=v|x|$ is the polar decomposition, then $v^{*}v$ is the range projection of $|x|$, is it wrong?

Comment: No. The range of $|x|$ is a limit of polynomials on $x^*x$, so it is contained in the range of $x^*$. And the closures agree, so $v^*v$ is indeed, both the range projection of $x^*$ and $|x|$.

Comment: Yes, so if we regard $v^{*}v$ as the range projection of $|x|$, what about the support projection now?

Comment: Oh, thanks, Martin. I suppose I got a comprehension.

Comment: The operator $|x|$ is positive, so selfadjoint, and thus its range and support projections are the same.